# How can I get IE to recognize NBSP as NBSP instead of a space?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

For the following JavaScript:

```
function EscapedString(str) {
  var obj = document.createElement("span");
  obj.innerHTML = str;
  return "&#" + (obj.textContent || obj.innerText).charCodeAt(0) + ";";
}

alert(EscapedString("&nbsp;"));
alert(EscapedString("&#160;"));
alert(EscapedString("\xA0"));
```

IE returns `&#32;` for each value instead of `&#160;` like every other browser correctly does. Is `.innerText` the wrong property for IE?

[Here's it running on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/usagu3/12/edit).

Comment: I have to convert all entity references to numeric references. I'd like to do it without using a huge list of entity names.

Comment: IE doesn't like the textContent property, so is probably doing something funky when it gets there. Does your code work if you swap it to `obj.innerText || obj.textContent`?

Comment: I tried it both ways, IE just doesn't seem to support textContent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I can access the value of the text node created by the innerHTML and that returns the correct value:

```
function EscapedString(str) {
  var obj = document.createElement("div");
  obj.innerHTML = str;
  return "&#" + (obj.firstChild.nodeValue || obj.textContent).charCodeAt(0) + ";";
}
```

[Here's the latest script running on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/usagu3/17/edit)
...[and here's the gist of the final code I ended up using](http://gist.github.com/316293)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Split up the '&' character from 'nbsp'

```
alert('&' + 'nbsp');
```

That worked for me. are you able to do that?

if not, perhaps you can convert to [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/)???

**edited**

```
  alert(String.fromCharCode(EscapedString("&nbsp;")))
```

Comment: Like this? 

`alert(EscapedString("&" + "nbsp;"));`

That still returns `&#32;` in IE.

Comment: And maybe try putting a space between & and nbsp.

Comment: ahhh, it's returning ascii to you. #32 is ascii code for space.

Comment: Right, the text I have to work with is `"&nbsp;"`, if possible I'd like to convert it (and all other named entities) to its numbered value, `"&#160;"`. Try running the JSBin link above in IE and you'll see what I mean/

Comment: It alerted an empty string, here's the JSBin I was using to test: http://jsbin.com/usagu3/17/edit